# How do I configure variable fonts in Context?

Tags: fonts, context

I would really like to use the light weight of a variable font I have ([Bahnschrift](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/bahnschrift)). Is this feature currently working in Context. I found an example online to make it work but I can't get it to work myself.

This is the example: https://gist.github.com/stone-zeng/dcdf3489b0efceb885dcee9fb82df30e

Has the syntax for usage changed?

Comment: There were discussions on variable fonts on the list lately. Perhaps check there and send a minimal example if it is still not working? (I guess then the only way out is then to get Hans' attention.)

Comment: Now that you have got some answer on the mailing list, maybe put an answer yourself to the question if that answer is working. That can help the next person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Context mailing list:

```
\starttext
Test Test

\definefont[bahnlight][name:bahnschriftlight*default]
\definefont[bahnsemilight][name:bahnschriftsemilight*default]
\definefont[bahnregular][name:bahnschriftregular*default]

\startMPcode
picture pic;
pic := thelabel(textext("\bahnlight This is Bahnschrift light in Metafont 0123456789"), (0, 0));
draw pic;
pic := thelabel(textext("\bahnsemilight This is Bahnschrift semilight in Metafont 0123456789"), (0, 15));
draw pic;
pic := thelabel(textext("\bahnregular This is Bahnschrift regular in Metafont 0123456789"), (0, 30));
draw pic;
\stopMPcode

\stoptext
```